# Monsters description and number of attacks

Tags: dnd-3.5e, pathfinder-1e

I need some clarification about how many attacks a monster can do and the way this is specified in the monster description.

I noticed that these entries are separated by "," or "and". Is there any difference or do both have the same meaning?

Then if a monster has multiple attacks (natural or not), how many of them can it do in a stabdard action?

For example, a dragon has **bite, 2 claws, 2 wings, tail slap**. In a full attack it gets 6 attacks, no questions, but what about in a standard action (let's say after a move)? Does it still have 6 attacks or must it choose only one of them?

And what about a Marilith? With:

> +1 longsword +24/+19/+14/+9 (2d6+8/17–20), 5 +1 longswords +24 (2d6+4/17–20), tail slap +17 (2d6+3 plus grab) or 6 slams +22 (1d8+7), tail slap +17 (2d6+3 plus grab)

... I'm more confused. Does this mean that it has ( 4 attacks (+24/+19/+14/+9) and/or 5 attacks (+24) and/or tail slap ) or ( 6 slams and/or tail slap )?

Generally I don't always understand where/when the "," is an **and** or an **exclusive or**.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This issue becomes clear once the rules on [actions in combat](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/combat/actionsInCombat.htm) and [natural weapons](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/specialAbilities.htm#naturalWeapons) have been carefully studied.

A good way to understand what kind of action each type of attack requires is to think of the actions *first*. Go to the [standard action](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/combat/actionsInCombat.htm#standardActions) subheading and observe that it only allows you to make a singular "[attack](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/combat/actionsInCombat.htm#attack)". The "[full attack](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/combat/actionsInCombat.htm#fullAttack)" option, which describes how to attack multiple times in a round, is described under [full-round actions](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/combat/actionsInCombat.htm#fullRoundActions). (In short: Standard action = one attack, full-round action = all attacks)

As for the [Marilith](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/monsters/demon.htm#marilith), the comma separating items in its full attack list is an AND. Thus, the full attack line describes two options:

1. Making its normal number of iterative attacks (stemming from its BAB of +16) with its primary weapon, followed by 5 attacks from its secondary weapons (held in other arms), followed by a single tail slap.
2. Foregoing all of its sword attacks to perform natural slam attacks with all of its appendages, and then a single tail slap.

Answer (score 7):

The same rules from the core rulebook apply to monsters as well as characters. Any creature has only one attack as a standard action.  Those lines are for full attacks, where they get everything separated by commas ("ands"), but have to choose between the "or"s.

So on a full attack the marilith can choose between 9 swords (including the iterative attacks on the primary sword) and a tail slap or 6 slams and a tail slap.